# Working with lists in Perl

Tags: perl

I have two lists a and b as follows:

```
a = ('church.n.01','church.n.02','church_service.n.01','church.n.04')  
b = ('temple.n.01','temple.n.02','temple.n.03','synagogue.n.01')
```

I want to find relatedness between members of a and b using function get_relatedness(arg1,arg2). How can I operate on a and b in Perl so that I will pass all possible combinations between a and b using two nested for loops in Perl.

Please help me to solve this as I am new to Perl.

Comment: How do you define relatedness here?

Comment: @Vijay: The question defines "find relatedness" to mean "call the function get_relatedness(arg1, arg2)". The question is answerable without needing to know what happens inside that function.

Answer (score 1):

```
my @a = ('church.n.01','church.n.02','church_service.n.01','church.n.04');
my @b = ('temple.n.01','temple.n.02','temple.n.03','synagogue.n.01');

use Data::Dumper; 
print Dumper [ get_relatedness(\@a, \@b) ];

sub get_relatedness {
  my ($c, $d) = @_;

  return map { my $t=$_; map [$t, $_], @$d } @$c;
}
```

output

```
$VAR1 = [
      [
        'church.n.01',
        'temple.n.01'
      ],
      [
        'church.n.01',
        'temple.n.02'
      ],
      [
        'church.n.01',
        'temple.n.03'
      ],
      [
        'church.n.01',
        'synagogue.n.01'
      ],
      [
        'church.n.02',
        'temple.n.01'
      ],
      [
        'church.n.02',
        'temple.n.02'
      ],
      [
        'church.n.02',
        'temple.n.03'
      ],
      [
        'church.n.02',
        'synagogue.n.01'
      ],
      [
        'church_service.n.01',
        'temple.n.01'
      ],
      [
        'church_service.n.01',
        'temple.n.02'
      ],
      [
        'church_service.n.01',
        'temple.n.03'
      ],
      [
        'church_service.n.01',
        'synagogue.n.01'
      ],
      [
        'church.n.04',
        'temple.n.01'
      ],
      [
        'church.n.04',
        'temple.n.02'
      ],
      [
        'church.n.04',
        'temple.n.03'
      ],
      [
        'church.n.04',
        'synagogue.n.01'
      ]
    ];
```

Answer (score 1):

To compare all combinations of elements in the two arrays using two nested loops, you just need to loop through one and, for each element of the first array, do an inner loop over the elements of the second array:

```
my @a = ('church.n.01','church.n.02','church_service.n.01','church.n.04');
my @b = ('temple.n.01','temple.n.02','temple.n.03','synagogue.n.01');

my $relatedness;

for my $outer (@a) {
  for my $inner (@b) {
    $relatedness += get_relatedness($outer, $inner);
  }
}
```